# What is the difference between Extrinsic and Dispatchable?

Tags: runtime

What is the difference between an Extrinsic and a Dispatchable?

Comment: You shouldn't repeat the title of the question in the question body. It's best to use the body of the question to add more context or to describe in what ways you tried to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "dispatchable" concept comes from FRAME. When somebody says `Dispatchable` they mean one of the entrypoints in a pallet.

For example, Balance's [`transfer`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/87ebfdbcf8242c04856e3881a78ea0bc369d77a2/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L275) is a dispatchable. Alternatively, it might be referred as a `Call`, e.g. [`Call::transfer`](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_balances/pallet/enum.Call.html#variant.transfer).

[Extrinsic](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/extrinsics/) is something that gets included in a block. Typically, it is a transaction that is sent by a user. Within FRAME every extrinsic specifies the [dispatchable](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/9a6d706d8db00abb6ba183839ec98ecd9924b1f8/primitives/runtime/src/generic/unchecked_extrinsic.rs#L53).